# ModalPopUpExtender with checkbox validation

Tags: validation, checkbox, modalpopupextender

I have an AJAX Application that I have been working on.  At this point in the development - I have a modalpopupextender with a warning message and an OK and Cancel button.  I have just been tasked with changing this to be three checkboxes and having the OK button disabled until all three boxes have been checked.  I'm having a difficult time trying to accomplish this.  I'm not sure if I should use a checkboxlist control or just three checkboxes.  I am also not sure if the enabling/disabling of the button should be handled through javascript or codebehind.  I have tried a little of both - with no success so any guidance is very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Three checkboxs would seem to work quite well if you ask me.. you can have each check box run the same validation function to check on the other 2. Also, i have found that using 'this.disable=true' would work quite well for what you are trying to accomplish. This way everything is handled under JS and there is no need to use the codebehind.

```
function validate() {
    if ('checkbox is not checked')
        return;
    if ('checkbox2 is not checked')
        return;
    if ('checkbox3 is not checked')
        return;  
    submit.disabled = false;
}
```